# sum only values with specified bool with core data

Tags: swift, core-data, arguments

I have a tableview with values. The database is made with core data. You can set the values to true or false. I only want to sum the values with true. To sum the values i have this code.

```
func printData() {
        //Shorthand Argument Names
        //let request: NSFetchRequest<Gegenstand> = Gegenstand.fetchRequest()
        //let records = try! context.fetch(request) as [NSManagedObject]
        let sum = ViewController.liste.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.value(forKey: "gewicht") as? Double ?? 0) }
                print("Gesamtgewicht: \(sum) kg")
                gewicht = sum
                if gewicht > 3500 {
                    gewichtLabel.textColor = .red
                    gewichtLabel.text = "\(gewicht) kg"
        }
        
    }
```

I tried it with an if-function but i don't know to use it with core data.

Comment: You can either use `filter` before `reduce` or add a check inside the closure for `reduce` but I guess you tried the latter but it didn't work? What was the problem with that? And why are you using `value(forKey:)` instead of accessing the property directly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Seems pretty clear to me

Answer (score 0):

Create a coreData fetchRequest with isValue=true,

Calculate the sum of return fetchRequest

```
 func fetchAllWithTrue() -> [Gegenstand] {
                    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: Gegenstand)
                    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: “isValue== YES")
                    do {
                        let fetchedObjects = try coreDataManager.context.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [Gegenstand]
                        return fetchedObjects
                    } catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        return [Gegenstand]()
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of it in Core Data if you want. Filter for `true` filtering with an `NSPredicate`, and have Core Data calculate the sum using `NSExpression`.

First set up the fetch request to get only entries where the property is `true` and make sure it returns dictionary-type results (I don't know what your boolean is called, so here I'm calling it `flag`. Put your property name there):

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Gegenstand")
fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "flag = true")
```

Then set up an `NSExpressionDescription` that can get the sum of `gewicht` values:

```
let sumExpression = NSExpression(format: "sum:(gewicht)")
let sumExpressionDescription = NSExpressionDescription()
sumExpressionDescription.expression = sumExpression
sumExpressionDescription.resultType = .double
sumExpressionDescription.name = "gewichtSum"
```

What this does is create a new kind of property that Core Data understands where the value is the sum the values of `gewicht` and is named `gewichtSum`. Fetch requests know how to use that kind of property. You do it like this:

```
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [ sumExpressionDescription ]
```

Since the fetch uses `dictionaryResultType`, running the fetch returns an array of dictionaries. It's an array because `fetch` always returns an array, but here there's only one entry. The dictionary in that array entry has a key called `gewichtSum` for a `Double` property that was calculated from the expression above. You get the value like this:

```
do {
    let result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    if result.count > 0,
        let sumInfo = result[0] as? [String:Double],
        let gewichtSum: Double = sumInfo["gewichtSum"] {
        print("Sum: \(gewichtSum)")
    }
} catch {
    ...
}
```

The `print` statement above prints the sum of all `gewicht` values where `flag` is true. It only includes true values for `flag` because of the `NSPredicate`, and it contains the sum because of the expression description.

Answer (score 0):

this is now my solution. I hope it is like practice. I look forward to your comments.

```
//Gewicht summieren
func printData() {
    //Shorthand Argument Names
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Gegenstand> = Gegenstand.fetchRequest()
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "eingepackt = true")
    
    do {
        let gesamtListe = try context.fetch(request)
        let sum = gesamtListe.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.value(forKey: "gewicht") as? Double ?? 0) }
                        print("Gesamtgewicht: \(sum) kg")
                        //gewicht = sum
                        if sum > 3500 {
                            gewichtLabel.textColor = .red
                            gewichtLabel.text = "\(sum) kg"
                        } else {
                            gewichtLabel.textColor = .black
                            gewichtLabel.text = "\(sum) kg"
                        }
    
    } catch {
        print("Gesamtgewicht konnte nicht berechnet werden.")
    }
    
}
```